# Visual Studio 2019 & Xamarin iOS - Simulator issues

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019

I've been trying to rework some pages that needed a change.
When I've edited a xaml page and corresponding xaml.cs page when Visual Studio built the page and ran it on the simulator it behaved like I did no change on it.
[image]

I've tried cleaning and building and cleaning and rebuilding my solution but to no avail.

There are some issues with running the simulator as well when sometimes it would start the app normally and the next time I start it I need to kill simulator completely and then re-run it
Is there some kind of setting that I've missed to set-up?

Comment: Hi , what is the version of VS , and could you share a screenshot with xaml previewer ? Such as this :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/evdgL.png

Comment: I've the same issue. Using VS ver. 16.7.7 and latest xamarin ios SDK (14.2.0.12). It says "Initialized agent" and "Xaml changed for ViewName.xaml in projectName, sending to app..." Any fix ?

Answer (score 0):

When you are making changes to xaml in debugging mode, you must hit save button to tell VS to push changes to emulator. The screenshot you provided clearly says that you didn't hit save. Also you must to enable hot reload for Xamarin. VS Options -> Xamarin -> Hot Reload.

Comment: Hot Reload is enabled:
`[HotReload] (2020-06-20 01:19:59.4): INFO: HotReload: Initialized Agent.
[HotReload] (2020-06-20 10:20:03.9): INFO: XAML Hot Reload Connected and Ready.`
and even after hitting save, I did not get the page that VS should be building.

Comment: Please keep in mind that you cannot edit corresponding xam.cs file while running debugger. You can only make changes to visual elements in xaml view.

Comment: I've tried editing a XAML file, for visual elements, while the debugger was off, and after saving the file and checking the Hot Reload, it still produced the page that is not correct after restarting the simulator